# Harbor Breeze Fan lights go out after 20 minutes

Tags: ceiling-fan

Harbor Breeze Fan lights (3) go out after 20 minutes or so but fan keeps working on a single wall switch. I have same fan in another room works fine. I just installed this one yesterday. I can turn the wall switch off and back on lights come on for 2 seconds and then back out but fan keeps working. Seems to be the same candelera bulbs on this fan as the other ... they came with the fan.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are they incandescent?   Try changing them all to LED.  If that fixes it, it was a thermal issue,  are they all LED? Install one incandescent (keep the rest LED), if that fixes it, it's an electronics  issue.

Comment: All are incandescent and get really hot...same as living room fan but living room doesn't shut off. I will have to get some LED with the smaller candelabra screw fixtures.   Thanks I will give it a shot when I can

Comment: With most fans like this, there is a modular block in the lower wiring compartment of the fan itself.  This mod block connects all the lights and fan motor to the house wiring.  I am going to say that there is a bad connection in that block that is overheating, expanding and loosing contact.

Comment: Do both fans have remotes?  Did you change the remote code on one of them?

Answer (score 1):

In modern fans there is a current limiter, these devices limit the wattage of the lamps and they do go bad, I have had to bypass them in my personal fans but when on the job they have to be replaced in this case it is cheaper to replace the fan. Some are electronic 3 wire and some are simple 2 wire from what I have found. If changing to a lower wattage lamp won't fix it the current limiter is bad.

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of a watt regulator in my ceiling fan?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-watt-regulator-in-my-ceiling-fan)

Comment: The government mandated the limited the wattage , safety, energy savings, nanny state you pick. But the DOE passed it for energy savings ( I do get tied of the regulations that cause more problems than good) how many fans have been tossed? Wasting way more energy in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

With most fans like this, there is a modular block in the lower wiring compartment of the fan itself. This mod block connects all the lights and fan motor to the house wiring. I am going to say that there is a bad connection in that block that is overheating, expanding and loosing contact.