# What is this thing I found in my ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

Does anyone know what this is? I found it in one of my ceiling fans. It failed which caused the lights to stop working, but I removed it and now everything works fine. It was on the switched light leg, and had a common going to it [image: Thing in my ceiling fan]

Comment: check the parts catalog for your fan

Comment: It's a wattage limiter. See this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1511/18078

Comment: Looks like a ballast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Hunter" is the fan manufacturer. I haven't been able to find the model number or part number imprinted here on their website; there may be another model number somewhere on the fan that you could look up.

Given that it says "Output 120V~300W Tungsten", I am guessing that this is intended to control the fan's light fixture (Tungsten referring to old-style incandescent bulbs, and 300W being a reasonable power draw for a set of four 75W bulbs of that sort.) At a wild guess, I'd suspect that it's a remote control relay or dimmer. The fact that bypassing it enabled the lights tends to confirm this.

If so... It may not have "failed", it might just have been dimmed/switched off. Do you have the remote for this fan? If so, did you try operating that before you removed this part, making sure the remote had new batteries?

If it really has failed, you'd need to talk to Hunter to make sure what it actually is and decide whether you need a replacement.